# How to send(POST) xml file using volley in android

Tags: android, android-volley

Is there a way to send an xml file using POST query in Volley? The
file contains products like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<products_list>
    <product>
        <tag1></tag1>
        <tag2></tag2>
        <tag3></tag3>
    </product>
    <product>
        <tag1></tag1>
        <tag2></tag2>
        <tag3></tag3>
    </product>
    ...
</products_list>
```

I know that Volley has StringRequest but how do I transfer a file like I listed above to server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getBodyContentType()` and `getBody()` of the [Request](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/android-l-preview_r2/src/com/android/volley/Request.java) object are used by Volley's [HurlStack](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/android-l-preview_r2/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/HurlStack.java) and [HttpClientStack](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/android-l-preview_r2/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/HttpClientStack.java) to grab the data to be pushed. You should override those methods and specify the request as POST.

#### An adaptation of the code provided in [basic Volley training](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html#simple)

```
// Create the request queue
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

// Create the request object
String url = "http://www.example.com/";
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
        new Response.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // TODO handle the response
            }

        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO handle the error
            }

        }
) {

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=" +
                getParamsEncoding();
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        String postData = FooBar.getPostData(); // TODO get your final output
        try {
            return postData == null ? null :
                    postData.getBytes(getParamsEncoding());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            // TODO consider if some other action should be taken
            return null;
        }
    }

};

// Schedule the request on the queue
queue.add(stringRequest);
```